# asp-route-id does not pass parameter value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This table correctly populates with `@device.DeviceId` but does not pass `@device.DeviceId` to the controller action.

```razor
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    @foreach (var device in @Model.Devices)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@device.DeviceId</td>
            <td>@device.DeviceName</td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="DeleteDevice"
                   asp-controller="Device"
                   asp-route-id="@device.DeviceId" asp->
                    Delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The controller action signature is

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteDevice(int deviceId)
```

The action is called but `deviceId` = 0.

How do I ensure `@device.DeviceId` is correctly passed to the action?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Either change the controller action to:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteDevice(int id)
```

or, change the `a` tag so that the `asp-route-*` attribute matches the name of the parameter, like so:

```razor
<a asp-action="DeleteDevice"
   asp-controller="Device"
   asp-route-deviceId="@device.DeviceId">
    Delete
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jamie Dunstan

Comment: ah, the action method had a different name thats why it wasn't being initialized! Thanks man!

Comment: Can anyone explain why the parameter must be named "id"? It's this kind of stuff that really gets to me and the reason why so many people avoid dot net.