# How do I route a value of an IdentityUser (like Username) and not the entire object?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So my View looks like this:

```
@model List<ListUsers>



<div class="card-deck">
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <div class="card m-3" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width:30.5%">

            <div class="card-header">
                <h5>@user.FriendId</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h2>@user.FriendName</h2>
            </div>


            <div class="card-footer text-center">
                <a asp-controller="account" asp-action="showprofile" asp-route-id="@user"
                   class="btn btn-primary">ShowProfile</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Even if I write

```
"asp-route-id="@user.FriendId"
```

(and I can see in the source code of the page in the browser that the ID is appended in the url) it hands the entire IdentityUser Object to the corresponding actionmethod. I just want the string.

This doesn't work either.

```
"asp-route-id="@user.FriendId.ToString()"
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to also show your account controller with the showprofile action method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First confirm the field type of FriendId, receive the `same type` of parameter in the showprofile action, and receive the parameter with `"id"` variable name.

```
    public IActionResult showprofile(int id)//if it is string type,use 'string id' to receive
    {
       // do what you want 
        return View();
    }
```

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850967/12884742).

Comment: Wow, thank you. I didn't know it has to be received with the parameter "id", i thought it could be called whatever. I was stuck on this for hours, thank you!!!!!